# iOS 8 / 9: Losing app specific data in NSUserDefaults upon rebooting phone and acting on push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, nsuserdefaults, ios9

I have observed that on iOS 8 and iOS 9, every time I reboot an iOS device and then send a push notification without opening the app, upon acting on that push notification, all my app specific data in NSUserDefaults will be lost. Opening the app brings the data back. Below are the repro steps.

Pre-requisite: app has actionable push notifications.

Repro steps:

1. Have the app installed on the phone, then power off the phone.
2. Reboot and unlock the phone, but do NOT open the app.
3. Lock the phone.
4. Send an actionable push notification to the phone.
5. Act on the notification on the lockscreen.

At this point, the delegate method `application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler` gets called. In this method if I put an NSLog that dumps all contents of `NSUserDefaults`, I would notice that all app-specific data were lost. Only non-app-specific data was there, things like `AppleKeyboards` and `AppleLanguages`. If my notification handler wants to access app specific data, it'll fail. Launching the app will bring back the data. Acting on push notifications in other scenarios (no reboot) is also fine.

I have already filed a bug report to Apple a while ago, they acknowledged the issue and said that they believe it was fixed in iOS 9. However in iOS 9.0.1 I'm still observing this issue. Prior to the issue happening I am getting the following device log:

> `Sep 28 15:10:53 iPhone identityservicesd[52] <Warning>: [Warning] sqlite3 error in _Bool CSDBRecordStoreSaveWithPreAndPostCallbacksAndTransactionType(CSDBRecordStoreRef, CSDBRecordStoreSaveCallback, CSDBRecordStoreSaveCallback, CSDBRecordConflictPolicy, CSDBSqliteTransactionType, CFErrorRef *): disk I/O error
>   Sep 28 15:10:53 iPhone identityservicesd[52] <Warning>: [Warning] sqlite3 error in _Bool CSDBRecordStoreSaveWithPreAndPostCallbacksAndTransactionType(CSDBRecordStoreRef, CSDBRecordStoreSaveCallback, CSDBRecordStoreSaveCallback, CSDBRecordConflictPolicy, CSDBSqliteTransactionType, CFErrorRef *): disk I/O error
>   Sep 28 15:10:53 iPhone identityservicesd[52] <Error>: Error saving record store: CSDBRecordSQLite/10
>   Sep 28 15:10:53 iPhone amfid[203] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>   Sep 28 15:10:53 iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[202] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/361D78B8-51C4-44F6-9C7A-4A4B100A1A08 (sandbox)
>   Sep 28 15:10:53 iPhone securityd[91] <Error>:  SecDbRecordChange db <SecDbConnection rw open> changed outside txn`

Apple hasn't responded for nearly two months now, I'm just wondering whether anyone has seen this issue. This issue impairs the reliability of the app as push notification action doesn't always work and the user won't know why. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I cannot quickly test it, but had similar observations in the past. What will happen if you call NSProcessInfo's processName before asking for the defaults?